# Check specific date and comparing start time and end time based on the timepicker and datepicker if overlaps

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker

I need to do a room booking app. I want to take the date from the datepicker value, then start time and end time from the timepicker value.

For that, I want to check for the selected date. Then, check if the start time and end time overlaps in any way whether start time, end time or in between on the selected date. I have been searching for the solution but did not find one.

Example :

User A : date=27 may 2013 start time=10pm end time=12pm

User B : date=28 may 2013 start time=10pm end time=12pm

if I am User C,and I also want that 10-12pm time slot at 27 may 2013,how do I compare for the date,then compare the start time and end time if the time slot is already taken by User A.

Hopefully someone can point me out in right the direction - I'm new in Android. Any help would be appreciated,thanks!

My Timepicker code:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerStartListener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        // set current time into textview
        textStartTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str(hour)).append(":").append(padding_str(minute)));

    }
};

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerEndListener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        // set current time into textview           
        textEndTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str(hour)).append(":").append(padding_str(minute)));

    }
};

private static String padding_str(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

My DatePicker code:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
           .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));
    }
};



@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
    case START_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerStartListener, hour, minute, false);
    case END_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerEndListener, hour, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't these date/time pickers have the ability to provide `Date` objects? As `Date` implements `Comparable` of itself, you're basically done wrt comparisons.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't really understand the second paragraph. Could you please try to explain your request once again?

Comment: @Zabri hi,let's say I pick a date 27th May 2013,I then pick a start and end time,let's say 10-12pm.I want to compare the start and end time if the time pick by another user is overlaps by what I choose including the date,cos maybe next day the time slot is empty.I hope you can help me

Comment: @fge hi,I cannot find what you mean,can you point me to any example that I can see,thanks

Comment: @kon Sorry, I just can't understand your English... :(

Comment: @Zabri sorry my english is not so good,I try again,
User A : date=27 may 2013 start time=10pm end time=12pm,
User B : date=28 may 2013 start time=10pm end time=12pm,

if I am User C,and I also want that 10-12pm timeslot at 27 may 2013,how do I compare for the date,then compare the start time and end time if the timeslot is already taken by User A.I hope you understands me,btw thanks for taking interest in my question,any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume there is already a reservation in the system. Let's call it *Reservation A*. And let's call the reservation the user of the application is trying to make *Reservation B*.

Each of those reservations start and end at certain points in time. If you represent those points by instances of the [`Calendar` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), you can then compare between the instances to find out whether the reservations overlap.

You can do something like this:

```
Calendar resAstart = Calendar.getInstance(); // Start of Reservation A
Calendar resAend = Calendar.getInstance(); // End of Reservation A
Calendar resBstart = Calendar.getInstance(); // Start of Reservation B
Calendar resBend = Calendar.getInstance(); // End of Reservation B
```

The calendars get initialized to current time, so you need to clear them up because you aren't interested in seconds and milliseconds. If you didn't do this, comparing two calendars for equality would probably return false even if they had the same day, month, year, hour and minute set.

```
resAstart.clear();
// the same for resAend, resBstart and resBend
```

Now you need to set the calendars up.

```
resAstart.set(Calendar.YEAR, /* the year when Reservation A starts */);
resAstart.set(Calendar.MONTH, /* the month when Reservation A starts */);
// and so on
// the same for resAend, resBstart and resBend
```

Now you need to compare the values. If the reservations should overlap, something of these scenarios would have to happen:

1. Start of *Reservation B* is the same as start of *Reservation A*.
2. Start of *Reservation B* is between start and end of *Reservation A*.
3. End of *Reservation B* is the same as end of *Reservation A*.
4. End of *Reservation B* is between start and end of *Reservation A*.
5. Start of *Reservation B* is before start of *Reservation A* **AND** end of *Reservation B* is after end of *Reservation A*.

In code it could look like this:

```
boolean overlap = false;
if (resBstart.equals(resAstart)) { // scenario 1
    overlap = true;
} else if (resBstart.after(resAstart) && resBstart.before(resAend)) { // scenario 2
    overlap = true;
} else if (resBend.equals(resAend)) { // scenario 3
    overlap = true;
} else if (resBend.after(resAstart) && resBend.before(resAend)) { // scenario 4
    overlap = true;
} else if (resBstart.before(resAstart) && resBend.after(resAend)) { // scenario 5
    overlap = true;
}
```

Now the value of `overlap` tells you whether the reservations overlap or not.

I hope it's understandable and that it helps.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,I will try to understand first,anything can I ask you? thanks again

Comment: Yes, if you have a question, feel free to ask.